# Python: is_set/partial update pattern - how to recognize if a member was explicitly set in constructor?

Tags: python

In my class `BaseFoo`, I want to determine which arguments of its subclass `Foo` were passed explicitly in the constructor:

```
class BaseFoo:
    def __init__(self, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at):
        self.created_at = created_at
        self.updated_at = updated_at
        self.deleted_at = deleted_at
        self.is_set = {}

class Foo(BaseFoo):

    def __init__(self, friend_id: int = None, start_time: datetime = None, id: int = None, end_time: datetime = None, created_at=None,
                 updated_at=None,
                 deleted_at=None):
        super().__init__(created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
        self.id = id
        self.friend_id = friend_id
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
```

My goal is to properly populate the `is_set` field of a `BaseFoo`/`Foo` instance according to what has been set explicitly by the constructor/setters. Here are a few examples of my end goal:

```
# input
foo = Foo(friend_id=1)
print(foo.is_set)
#output
# {"friend_id": True}

foo = Foo()
print(foo.is_set)
#output
# {}

foo = Foo(start_time=None)
foo.friend_id = 3
print(foo.is_set)
#output
# {"start_time": True, "friend_id": True}

foo = Foo(start_time=datetime.datetime.now())
foo.friend_id = 3
print(foo.is_set)
#output
# {"start_time": True, "friend_id": True}
```

I'm *almost* where I want to be with this method in `BaseFoo`:

```
    def __setattr__(self, attrname, val):
        import inspect
        f = inspect.currentframe()
        if 'self' in f.f_back.f_locals and issubclass(type(f.f_back.f_locals['self']), BaseFoo):
            # call came from __init__
            if attrname != "is_set":
                self.is_set = self.is_set if hasattr(self, "is_set") else {}
                self.is_set[attrname] = True
            super().__setattr__(attrname, val)
        else:
            if attrname != "is_set":
                self.is_set = self.is_set if hasattr(self, "is_set") else {}
                self.is_set[attrname] = True
                super().__setattr__(attrname, val)
```

The only missing piece here is that I need to know, in case `__setattr__` has been triggered by the `__init__` constructor, whether the `val` of `attrname` has been explicitly set by the user (if it has been explicitly set to its default value).

Is this possible?

Comment: The usual approach for this, if `None` is something users can pass explicitly, is to have your own "no value" object that users aren't supposed to pass. It's a lot more reliable than trying to mess with stack frames. (If you're thinking it doesn't sound reliable enough, well, messing with stack frames is even less reliable.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` and parse the arguments manually.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - Thanks. can you give a minimal example of what you're suggesting with the "no value" object? I'm not sure I understand how that would bypass frames. For now I've added "NoneValue" as a default value for all types, and with a simple check in the above code I can re-assign `None` to that without changing `is_set`. How would your example work?

Comment: Simplest example would be `_no_value = object()` and then use that as your default, but libraries typically write up something with a nicer `__repr__`. Now if you get `_no_value` as a parameter value, you know the user didn't explicitly pass `None`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - so in this case I would be using default parameters in the constructor (I guess this is a must?) and only do the check in `__setattr__’ without having to check stuff in the frames?